# Maintaining dynamic changes after web browser's back button pressed

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, back-button, browser-cache

If I had a button on the page that changes the css so all of the text will be blue, is there any way that if a user clicks a new link, then clicks the back button, the text on the page will still be blue?

I thought about caching, but I assume the browser's cached page would be pre-blue-button-press, but might there be some way to tell the browser to re-cache the page within the blue-button javascript function?  Or is there any other way to get this same functionality?

Comment: Instead of JS change you could forward them to a new page (that's blue)... that'll be stored in the history.  Or use [HTML5 History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).  Or use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) to store the history state in HTML4/5 browsers.  Or set a cookie/local cache value, and on page load look for that value - if it's there switch the colour to blue

Comment: @Rudu, the cookie idea was definitely thrown around, which might work, but assuming people have an HTML5 browser isn't my preferred route.  I'd also hate for the people to have to load new pages for simple changes (real use case is small and frequent changes, rather than a global one like I described)  Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: I was contemplating interrogating the link's visited state and came across this paranoid response to history probing. Sheez what an overreaction in my opinion.... http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/